# MySQL count "IN" statement matches

Tags: mysql

In a query like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM table 
WHERE field 
IN (SELECT field2 FROM table2 WHERE condition)
```

How I can order the returned rows by the number of records matching in the IN statement ?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean.  The number of records matching in the `IN ()` subquery is a scalar value, and so ordering by it does not make sense. Post a sample recordset and a sample expected output if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you mean by the number of distinct values in table 2 that match.

```
select t.ID, count(t2.field2) 
from table t left outer join
     (select distinct field2
      from table2
      where condition
     ) t2
     on t.field = t2.field2
group by t.id
order by count(t2.field2) desc;
```

Why is it structured like this?  The `left outer join` ensures that all rows from `table` are in the result set.  The `distinct` ensures that duplicate rows in `table2` do not result in duplicate rows in the output.  `count(t2.field2)` counts the number of matches in the second table, so it will be `0` when there is no match (as opposed to `count(*)` which would be `1` in that case).

This is assuming that `id` is unique in `table`.

Answer (score 0):

try JOIN-ing ON where those fields are equal and then do a COUNT(*) like below, then you can ORDER BY that COUNT(*) (representing occurences of field = field2)

```
SELECT table.ID,COUNT(*) as occurrence 
FROM table INNER JOIN table2
ON table.field = table2.field2
WHERE condition
GROUP BY table.ID
ORDER BY occurrence
```